# PHP7 & return hints on abstract class implementations

Tags: php, php-7

Curious.

Given this class:

```
abstract class AbstractMapper 
{
   public abstract function get($id)
}
```

Whose child is a Sprocket mapper

```
class SprocketMapper extends AbstractMapper
{
    public function get($id) : Sprocket
    {
        // get it, return it
    }
}
```

If Sprocket is a POPO:

Is the proper form, simply to not put a return hint on get() at the abstract parent level? Or would you create an interface type for these POPOs that all such mappers can type hint?

Thanks!

Comment: I would implement as you have here: children may accept less specific formal parameters and return more specific values without viooating LSP.

Comment: LSP is why I went this way, but it leaves my AbstractMapper feeling un-php7-y!  Thanks for weighing in!

Comment: Well, if there is a Sprocket base class, abstract get could return that, though your concrete get implementations may appreciate the flexibility to return either a Sprocket or null.

Comment: If it was `Java`, one would do interface called say `AbstractSprocket` and return it in `AbstractMapper::get()`. `SprocketMapper::get()` will continue to return `AbstractSprocket` interface, but in reality it will be `Sprocket` class. If this is what you need, I can make it as an answer.

Comment: Hm I had put that in the question; I suppose I was looking for a hard rationale for "to interface or no" -- seems the jury is out!  I feel dirty excluding hints for some reason -- but to satisfy in this case is a lot more work. Seems there's no benefit to either approach.